# Receive data from Nodejs Module.Exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have created a node module

**Module file :**

```
var functions = {};
functions.test = function(){
  console.log("Invoked");
  return "Hello";
}
module.exports = functions;
```

**Main File :**

```
const FUNCTIONS = require('./modulefile');
var x = FUNCTIONS.test();
console.log(x);
```

Now, here I can see "`Invoked`" means function is getting executed.

But `x is undefined`, seems value is not getting returned.

How can I return value from `test()` to main file.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . `functions.test(){` is syntax error. Real code differs in some way that wasn't shown.

Comment: This would not work either. You have `tes` but calling `test`. Care to provide working code that demostrates the issue.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko updated. Its was a typo. The function is getting invoked properly but, not returning the data.

Comment: @estus updated.

Comment: MB your actual function. The one you have posted works as expected. So your question basically lacks [mcve]

Comment: @YuryTarabanko `var x = FUNCTIONS.test();` dosen't returns the value. `x` is getting undefined. While the function `test` in module is returning.

Comment: Not true :) https://repl.it/repls/RobustPrimaryVisitor The problem is some where else.

Comment: If the function returned data as shown, there would be no chance for it to not return it. As I mentioned, real code differs in some way.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks for help. The problem seems like, i was returning from inside of 2 way nested function and actual return is not happening, which is getting trapped somewhere. Using callback solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `callbacks`?

Hard to say what the underlying problem is considering people have got your code working.

Model file:

```
var functions = {
  test: function(callback) {
    console.log("Invoked");
    callback("Hello")
  }
}
module.exports = functions;
```

Other file:

```
var Functions= require('./functions');
var x
Functions.test(function (result) { x = result });
console.log(x);
```

Comment: it worked ! The problem seems, that i was returning from inside of 2 way nested function and actual return is not happening, which is getting trapped somewhere.

Comment: If the code is synchronous as shown, the callback is absolutely redundant.

Comment: @AtulSharma Then the question is possible duplicate of this popular one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, I replicated it and it works
check it out here https://repl.it/@Muhand1/module-export